# How to use column value as parameter in aggregation function in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, aggregate-functions

Given a certain table of type

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| t | r | 1 |
| t | r | 1 |
| n | j | 2 |
| n | j | 2 |
| n | j | 2 |

I would like to group on `A` and `B` and only take the number of rows specified by `C`

So the desired output would be

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| t | r | 1 |
| n | j | 2 |
| n | j | 2 |

I am trying to achieve that through this function but with no luck

```
df.groupby(['A', 'B']).agg(lambda x: x.head(df.C))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`groupby.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) and [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
out = df[df['C'].gt(df.groupby(['A', 'B']).cumcount())]
```

Or with a classical [`groupby.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html):

```
(df.groupby(['A', 'B'], sort=False, as_index=False, group_keys=False)
   .apply(lambda g: g.head(g['C'].iloc[0]))
)
```

output:

```
   A  B  C
0  t  r  1
2  n  j  2
3  n  j  2
```

Intermediates for the `groupby.cumcount` approach:

```
   A  B  C  cumcount  C > cumcount
0  t  r  1         0          True
1  t  r  1         1         False
2  n  j  2         0          True
3  n  j  2         1          True
4  n  j  2         2         False
```

Answer (score 4):

The following seems to work and is based on [`GroupBy.nth`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.nth.html):

```
df[::-1].groupby(['A', 'B'], as_index=False).nth(df['C'])
```

Output:

```
   A  B  C
3  n  j  2
2  n  j  2
0  t  r  1
```